# Moving disk space from /home to / on RHEL7.2 with xfs file system

Tags: lvm, xfs, rhel7

I've setup RHEL7 with default partitioning, and they partitioned it as following:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-home 100GB /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-root 50GB /
```

Both are on xfs filesystem. How can i shift most of my diskspace from /home to / ?

I've tried the below code

```
umount /home
lvreduce -rL -10G /dev/mapper/rhel-home
lvextend -rL +10G /dev/mapper/thel-root
```

But it doesnt seem to work because xfs file system does not support shrinking.

Comment: Let's see your outputs of 'pgdisplay', 'vgdisplay' and 'lvdisplay' please

Comment: Not to mention `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have space in your root filesystem, I would do:

```
mkdir /opt/home && mv /home/* /opt/home && umount /home && rmdir /home && ln -s /opt/home /home
```

At this point you can destroy your rhel-home volume and recreate it again with the desired (shrinked) size, adding the remaining space to your rhel-root volume, then:

```
rm /home && mkdir /home &&  mount /home && mv /opt/home/* /home/ && rmdir /opt/home
```

I know seems complicated but it works.

Comment: for your second command, should it be mkdir /home instead of rm /home?

Comment: it's the link that points to /opt/home created in the first command, so yes, it's rm. But you're roght, i missed a mkdir. Fixed thnx!

Comment: Do you happen to have a guide for destroy and recreating of logical volume

Comment: You can check here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: appreciate the advice Fredi =)